# `gpg --genkey` keeps asking for password when run from WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnupg

I'm using ubuntu from WSL2 and try to create a GPG keypair.

When running the command `gpg --genkey` the program ask for the keyphrase once and again in a loop and does not succeed even when typing the same password many times.

Any clue about what can be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `gpg --full-generate-key` works as expected.